# Nothing happens on query execution

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this simple code C# and SQL Server database:

```
int refcodenum = getOrderNum();
string refcode = "E" + refcodenum;
byte[] personalpic = getBarcode(refcodenum);

SqlCommand cm2 = new SqlCommand();
cm2.Connection = cn;
cm2.CommandText = "Update Clients set ReferenceNumber='" + refcode + "',ReferenceBarcode=@photo where NetNumber='"+id+"'";

cm2.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.Image, personalpic.Length).Value = personalpic;

// here like cursor stop
cm2.ExecuteNonQuery();

lastpage = "x";

File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\myimage.jpg");
```

I have run it but nothing happens on query execution I used `MessageBox` like that to identify the line that has the problem

```
int refcodenum = getOrderNum();
string refcode = "E" + refcodenum;
byte[] personalpic = getBarcode(refcodenum);

SqlCommand cm2 = new SqlCommand();
cm2.Connection = cn;

MessageBox.Show("1");

cm2.CommandText = "Update Clients set ReferenceNumber='" + refcode + "',ReferenceBarcode=@photo where NetNumber='"+id+"'";

MessageBox.Show("2");

cm2.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.Image, personalpic.Length).Value = personalpic;
MessageBox.Show("3");

// here cursor stops
cm2.ExecuteNonQuery();

// that messagebox isn't shown
MessageBox.Show("4");

lastpage = "x";
File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\myimage.jpg");
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: "cursor stops"? Do you mean the debugger stops on that line? Do you have a breakpoint there?

Comment: I mean like interpreter stops here nothing happens at all

Comment: C# is not interpreted, it's the debugger. Are you sure there's no breakpoint - red circle on the left ? No error is shown? Perhaps you could upload a screenshot.

Comment: I removed the whole condition statement (where .... '"+id+"') but nothing happens

Comment: What's in your output window?

Comment: It`s a function that runs on web browser control document completion I was assured that it runs line by line correctly through messagebox but the line I`m pointing by comment Is never passed It Seems like the rest of lines don`t exist

Comment: OK It`s now solved I was calling it while sqldatareader is reading and there was a confliction between reader and sqlcommand cm2

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

You haven't opened your Connection. See below.

You should also use the `using` syntax to make use of IDisposable

```
int refcodenum = getOrderNum();
string refcode = "E" + refcodenum;
byte[] personalpic = getBarcode(refcodenum);
var sqlCmdText = "Update Clients set ReferenceNumber='" + refcode + "',ReferenceBarcode=@photo where NetNumber='"+id+"'";

try
{
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection([YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE]))
    {
        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCmdText, sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.Image, personalpic.Length).Value = personalpic;
            sqlConnection.Open();

            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new DataException(ex.Message);
}
```